# A conformal class is a connected subset

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, conformal-geometry

Let $\mathcal{G}$ be the set of Riemannian metrics on a compact, smooth manifold $M$. Let $g \in \mathcal{G}$ and $[g]$ be its conformal class.

I recently read that since $[g]$ is the range of $C^{\infty}(M,\mathbb{R})$ under the map
\begin{equation}
f \longrightarrow e^{2f}g,
\end{equation}
it is a connected subset of $\mathcal{G}$.

I'm not sure how to see that this fact is true. Does it have something to do with the fact that $\mathcal{G}$ is a Frechet space with the $C^{\infty}$-topology? Or is there some simple, clear explanation which I am failing to see?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact $[g]$ is path-connected with respect to the $C^k$-, $C^\infty$-, or $C^{k,\alpha}$-topologies.

$C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$ is path-connected: if $f,h\in C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R})$, then $\gamma(t)=th+(1-t)f$ is a continuous path connecting them.  The map
$$ C^\infty(M,\mathbb{R}) \ni f \mapsto e^{2f}g \in \mathcal{G} $$
is continuous.  Hence the image of this map, namely $[g]$, is path-connected.

I usually just think of this argument as the observation that $t\mapsto e^{2th + 2(1-t)f}g$ is a continuous path from $e^{2f}g$ to $e^{2h}g$.